# How to apply changes to Puphpet config (via Vagrant)

Tags: vagrant, puphpet

I built my config with https://puphpet.com and have successfully deployed my virtual machine using `vagrant up`. Now I'm trying to customize it a little bit and see in the docs that there are two folders to run scripts in the VM: `puphpet/files/exec-always` and `puphpet/files/exec-once`.

I wrote a couple test BASH scripts and dropped them there but the only way I could "apply" these was if I destroy the VM completely and reprovision it from scratch. This takes an enormous amount of time.

What's the proper way to test and debug these scripts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `$ vagrant provision`!

Comment: I really wish there was a way to run exec-once / exec-always manually.. instead of having to run through the whole provisioning process.. it really makes setup a pain. Still better than setting up a new server manually though

Comment: @SgtPooki you can `$ vagrant ssh` then run `$ ./vagrant/puphpet/shell/execute-files.sh`

Comment: @JuanTreminio vagrant ssh -c "./vagrant/puphpet/shell/executei-files.sh" works too.. I was more worried about calling specific scripts in a more easy manner.. something like vagrant provision -i (where -i is interactive and you can approve any scripts)